# Add water effect on bitmap android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, effect

How can i add water waves in bitmap image?
i have found water ripple effect on touch event here: https://github.com/esteewhy/whater but can not implement on my single bitmap.
can anyone help in making water wave effect on my bitmap? 
or should i go for image processing? 
Thank you in advance.
Here is my sample code in which i have to make water reflection effect:

```
public static Bitmap reflection(Bitmap mainImage) {
       int width = mainImage.getWidth();
       int height = mainImage.getHeight();

       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       matrix.preScale(1, -1);

       reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainImage, 0,
               0, width, height , matrix, false);

        reflectedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
               (height + height), Config.ARGB_8888);

       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(reflectedBitmap);
       canvas.drawBitmap(mainImage, 0, 0, null);
       Paint defaultPaint = new Paint();
       canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height, defaultPaint);

       canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height-6 , null);
       Paint paint = new Paint();
       LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0,
               mainImage.getHeight(), 0, reflectedBitmap.getHeight()
                       , 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
       paint.setShader(shader);
       paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
       canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, reflectedBitmap.getHeight()
                , paint);
           return reflectedBitmap;
}
```