# Water reflection effect on bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap, effect, bitmapimage

I trying to achieve water reflection effect on bitmap. As I saw some apps called water reflection. I know how to do the reflection of the image but the wave on the image is what making me confused on how it is done.

see this image for example

[image]

I did many apps on bitmap manipulation but this is quite hard to achieve.
So any idea on where to start. Just an idea to start can be helpful.

Comment: Have You got solution, i have same problem

Comment: Did you find any solution how to create frame to produce a gif file or mp4?I have same issue too.I can create a rippled bitmap but can not find any way to produce moving wave and create frames.May you help me?

Comment: Butani I saw you are looking for this issue too , could you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any one needed, I tried some simple tricks to get as closer as water reflection effect. It is not great but it looks fine to me.

I used two methods

Bitmap reflection method (give bitmap as a parameter)

```
  public static Bitmap Reflection(Bitmap imageBitmap) {

           int width = imageBitmap.getWidth();
           int height = imageBitmap.getHeight();

           Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
           matrix.preScale(1, -1);

          Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap, 0,
                   0, width, height , matrix, false);

          Bitmap newbit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(reflectionImage, reflectionImage.getWidth()/8, reflectionImage.getHeight()/8, true);

          Bitmap newbit1=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(newbit, newbit.getWidth()*8, newbit.getHeight()*8, true);

          Bitmap scalednew=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(newbit1, width, height-(height/4), true);

          Bitmap newscaledone=overlay(scalednew);

       reflectionImage=newscaledone;

           Bitmap reflectedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
                   (height + height), Config.ARGB_8888);

           Canvas canvas = new Canvas(reflectedBitmap);
           canvas.drawBitmap(imageBitmap, 0, 0, null);
           Paint defaultPaint = new Paint();
           canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height, defaultPaint);

           canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height , null);
           Paint paint = new Paint();

           paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
           canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, reflectedBitmap.getHeight()
                    , paint);
               return reflectedBitmap;

}
```

Bitmap overlay method. I am taking a wave bitmap with some opacity to overlay on the reflected image. So that it may look like water.

```
 Bitmap wavebitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.waves1);

private static Bitmap overlay( Bitmap bmp2) {
     Bitmap bmp1=WaterReflectionMainActivity.wavebitmap;

      Bitmap bmp1new =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp1, bmp2.getWidth(), bmp2.getHeight(), true);

        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1new.getWidth(), bmp1new.getHeight(), bmp1new.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1new, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

Well this is my version of water effect, I know this looks shit.
So if anyone still got some better effect please share your code .
thank you

Comment: can you provide wave image that you used

Answer (score 2):

Tutorial related to this: http://www.xaraxone.com/webxealot/workbook34/page_4.htm
Also have a read at this question: [Add water effect on bitmap android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029393/add-water-effect-on-bitmap-android).
Have a read at both of them, i hope you will get an idea from this

You may also want to look through these: [1](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=2P9sxTaN2FMC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=how+to+create+water+reflection+in+bitmap&source=bl&ots=Mqei0MZ9J5&sig=Vqg2mgsQq1awNRucAC9XIim0FIA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KyL7UtaCHcelrQfF1YBw&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20create%20water%20reflection%20in%20bitmap&f=false), [2](http://snipplr.com/view/55170/), [3](http://designertoday.com/Tutorials/CorelDraw/680/Reflections.Corel.CorelDraw.9.Tutorial.aspx)

Comment: But there is no water effect tutorial which points to android.But good link sources though.

Comment: @sandeep doing through android should be similar i think, do you mind putting a tick to my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I will wait for some more closer answers and then mark the answer which helped me to achieve my goal here. I will surely upvote your answer as it has some good sources.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an idea but basically, what you need is to apply a deformation on the bottom part of the image, meaning that for each pixel on the bottom half, you compute a position to get it's color from the top picture.

Here's a pseudo code to give you a hint :

```
for (int x = 0;  x < width; x++) {

    for (int y = 0; y < img.height; y++) {

        // Compute a position on the original image
        // tweak the values heres to get the effect you want
        sourceX = x + (int) (cos(10000.0 / y) * 20); 
        sourceY = img.height - y - 1 +(int)( sin(y* 0.5) * 20); 

        // Maybe check the range of sourceX and source Y

        int color = img.getColor(sourceX, sourceY) 

        outptut.setColor(x, y + img.height, color); 
   }
}
```

Comment: I got a doubt. In the second last line -"img.get" . what are we trying to get here..?

Comment: img is the original image you want to add a reflection to. The img.get  is actually getting the color at the point sourceX, sourceY. output.set is actually output.setColor (i'll edit my answer accordingly)

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the code. I get the error on int color line.

Comment: in android its img.getPixel instead of img.getcolor

Comment: Yes, as I said, it's pesudo code as I only tested it in Processing (didn't have time to setup a full app test to modify an image)

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by masking may this code will help you

http://www.seeques.com/22527681/how-can-do-this-effect-in-android-may-be-android-bitmap-masking-effect.html

EDIT

also see this for reference

http://code.google.com/p/android-ripple-demo/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fkesalin%2FRippleDemo

https://github.com/esteewhy/whater

http://code.google.com/p/waterrippleeffect/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/watereffect/WaterEffectView.java?r=3

[android noise effect on bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690730/android-noise-effect-on-bitmap)

Comment: I already tried masking , but it doesn't look like water effect. but thanks for your answer.

Comment: your reference links are of ripple effect. I mean like for livewallpaper or animation. But I want water wave effect on still Bitmap image.

Comment: ya i know that but i thought that's help you in logic so i posted.